# How to get Particular Value from JsonObject?

Tags: angular, typescript

This is my Json Object and I am trying to retrieve the data from it but I am getting as undefined ,

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "message": "Task has been Retrieved",
    "employeepanel": {
        "taskno": 7,
        "taskdate": "2001-06-21",
        "createdby": "admin",
        "taskdescription": "create the product and deliever it by monday  ",
        "status": "assigned",
        "date": "2001-06-21",
        "tenure": 1,
        "employee": {
            "userId": 30,
            "userName": "xyz",
          
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I was trying to do , my function finds the task by id , and my api gives response in such format  now I have to get the userName from this

```
findbyId(event) {
    var selected_id = event.currentTarget.id
    const base_URL = 'http://localhost:8091/getbyTaskno/'+selected_id 
    this.http.get(base_URL, {
    }).subscribe(data => {
      if (data['status'] == '200' && data['message'] == 'Task has been Retrieved') {
      this.userIds=data['employeepanel.employee.userName']
     }else{
       alert("No task is present for the particular Employee")
     } })
  }
```

Comment: Put the api url (with a valid id) into your browser aand see what you get back

Answer (score 2):

Try accessing your properties and sub props with dot notation:

`this.userIds=data.employeepanel.employee.userName;`

Answer (score 2):

`data['employeepanel.employee.userName']` is wrong notation.

This would be sample code, assuming `data` is valid JSON:

```js
findbyId(event) {
    var selected_id = event.currentTarget.id;
    const base_URL = 'http://localhost:8091/getbyTaskno/'+selected_id;
    this.http.get(base_URL, {
    }).subscribe(data => {
        if (data.status === '200' && data.message === 'Task has been Retrieved') {
            this.userIds=data.employeepanel.employee.userName;
        } else {
            alert("No task is present for the particular Employee")
        }
    });
}
```

For better reference to JSON have a look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON#full_json_syntax).

```js
let data = {
    "status": 200,
    "message": "Task has been Retrieved",
    "employeepanel": {
        "taskno": 7,
        "taskdate": "2001-06-21",
        "createdby": "admin",
        "taskdescription": "create the product and deliever it by monday  ",
        "status": "assigned",
        "date": "2001-06-21",
        "tenure": 1,
        "employee": {
            "userId": 30,
            "userName": "xyz",
        }
    }
};

function getEmployeeUserName() {
  console.log("data.employeepanel.employee.userName is: ", data.employeepanel.employee.userName);
}
```

```css
.main {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<p class="main">Click the button to log the <code>.employeepanel.employee.userName;</code></p>
<button onclick="getEmployeeUserName()">Get Employee userName</button>
```

Comment: getting error something like this ,  error TS2339: Property 'employeepanel' does not exist on type 'Object'.

Comment: This means the returned JSON is either invalid or has no `employeepanel` property.
Can you add `console.log(data)` to the code where that if statement is and share some sample outputs?

Comment: {status: 200, message: "Task has been Retrieved", employeepanel: {…}}
employeepanel:
createdby: "admin"
date: "2001-06-21"
employee: {userId: 30, userName: "xyz", 
taskdescription: "create the product and deliever it by monday  "

__proto__: Object
message: "Task has been Retrieved"
status: 200

Comment: What you shared of course doesn't seem to be valid JSON.

Comment: Can you like paste complete output and create a paste on pastebin or something and share?